# C++ Implicit conversion about class inherit

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
using namespace std;

class A{
public:
    long a;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    long b;
};

void seta(A* data, int idx) {
    data[idx].a = 2;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    B data[4];
    for (int i = 0; i<4; ++i){
        data[i].a = 1;
        data[i].b = 1;
        seta(data, i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<4; ++i){
        std::cout << data[i].a << data[i].b;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The result print is `22221111`.

When I change `A::a` type to double, the result print is `20201111`.

When I change `A::a` type to float, the result print is `2107374182421073741821111`.

How it convered?

Comment: Arrays are not polymorphic in that regard. You just have a heap of undefined behavior going on.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer arithmetic does not work with run-time polymorphism. When you write  `data[idx]`, then `*data` must have the same dynamic type as is its static type. In other words, `data` must point to an object of type `A`, not some type that derives from `A`.

Since the above doesn't hold for your program, the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I want to know when A:a type is long, why data[idx].a can correct assign B:b value.to 2 ?

Comment: @fazzy because that is one possible outcome of undefined behaviour.

Comment: This is a interview questions, many people run many times，the result is the same. some people said the data[idx].a in the function seta can assign to B:b because the Implicit conversion 。I was so curious of it!

Answer (score 0):

You better initialize your attributes to 0 or -1 so you can figure out if it is changing or not.

```
    long b=0;
```

The random values you are getting are not values of conversion problem, it is undefined behavior going on as StoryTeller commented.

Finally, your data is not pointing to an object of type A which the reason behind all the mess.